# Spring WebFlux | How to wait till a list of Monos finish execution in parallel

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I want to send n-number of requests to a REST endpoint in parallel.I want to make sure these get executed in different threads for performance and need to wait till all n requests finish.

Only way I could come up with is using CountDownLatch as follows (please check the main() method. This is testable code):

```
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            
            int n = 10; //n is dynamic during runtime
    
            final CountDownLatch waitForNRequests = new CountDownLatch(n);
            //send n requests
            for (int i =0;i<n;i++) {
                var r = testRestCall(""+i);
                r.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe(res -> {
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>> Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " response:" +res.getBody());
                    
                    waitForNRequests.countDown();
                });
            }
    
    
            waitForNRequests.await(); //wait till all n requests finish before goto the next line
    
            System.out.println("All n requests finished");
            Thread.sleep(10000); 
        }

 

public static Mono<ResponseEntity<Map>> testRestCall(String id) {
    
            WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://reqres.in/api");
    
            JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
            request.put("name", "user"+ id);
            request.put("job", "leader");
    
            var res = client.post().uri("/users")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request.toString()))
    
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(Map.class)
                    .onErrorReturn(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).build());
            return res;
    
        }
```

This doesnt look good and I am sure there is an elegant solution without using Latches..etc
I tried following method,but I dont know **how to resolve following issues**:

1. Flux.merge() , contact() results in executing all n-requests in a single thread
2. How to wait till n-requests finish execution (fork-join)?

```
List<Mono<ResponseEntity<Map>>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
int n = 10; //n is dynamic during runtime
for (int i =0;i<n;i++) {
    var r = testRestCall(""+i);
    lst.add(r);
}

var t= Flux.fromIterable(lst).flatMap(Function.identity()); //tried merge() contact() as well
t.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe(res -> {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>> Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " response:" +res.getBody());
            ///??? all requests execute in a single thread.How to parallelize ?
        });

//???How to wait till all n requests finish before goto the next line
System.out.println("All n requests finished");

Thread.sleep(10000);
```

**Update:**

I found the reason why the Flux subscriber runs in the same thread, I need to create a ParallelFlux. So the correct order should be:

```
var t= Flux.fromIterable(lst).flatMap(Function.identity()); 
t.parallel()
 .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
 .subscribe(res -> {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>> Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " response:" +res.getBody());
            ///??? all requests execute in a single thread.How to parallelize ?
        });
```

Ref: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux

Comment: Do you know about `Mono/Flux#block`?

Comment: Yes, but which Mono should I block when I have a list of Monos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reactive you think not about threads but about concurrency.

Reactor executes non-blocking/async tasks on a small number of threads using `Schedulers` abstraction to execute tasks. `Schedulers` have responsibilities very similar to `ExecutorService`. By default, for parallel scheduler number of threads is equal to number of CPU cores, but could be controlled by `reactor.schedulers.defaultPoolSize’ system property.

In your example instead of creating multiple `Mono` and then merge them, better to use `Flux` and then process elements in parallel controlling concurrency.

```
Flux.range(1, 10)
    .flatMap(this::testRestCall)
```

By default, flatMap will process `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE = 256` number of in-flight inner sequences.

You could control concurrency `flatMap(item -> process(item), concurrency)` or use `concatMap` operator if you want to process sequentially. Check [flatMap(..., int concurrency, int prefetch)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-int-) for details.

```
Flux.range(1, 10)
    .flatMap(i -> testRestCall(i), 5)
```

The following test shows that calls are executed in different threads

```
@Test
void testParallel() {
    var flow = Flux.range(1, 10)
            .flatMap(i -> testRestCall(i))
            .log()
            .then(Mono.just("complete"));

    StepVerifier.create(flow)
            .expectNext("complete")
            .verifyComplete();

}
```

The result log

```
2022-12-30 21:31:25.169  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.3                   : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.170  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.2                   : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.169  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.169  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-8] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.7                   : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.169  INFO 43383 --- [tor-http-nio-11] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.10                  : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.169  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.6                   : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.169  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-9] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.8                   : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.170  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-6] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.5                   : | onComplete()
2022-12-30 21:31:25.378  INFO 43383 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.4                   : | onComplete()
```

Comment: even if I use concurrency, how can I wait till all the requests are processed ?

Comment: `Flux` will complete when all requests are processed

Comment: it will continue in the react manner, i dont want to execute next line in the program till all the requests are finished processing.

Comment: you can chain with `.then(…)` to wait until publisher completes before subscribe to the next publisher

Comment: then ,the requests are not executed in parallel  right?. i want to send n-requests parallelly, and wait till last  of the request (longest time takeing) finish the execution.

Comment: Why?  It looks like you still thinking in threads ;-). ‘Flux.flatMap` always subscribes in parallel.

Comment: i did this, but the "theadName" is always the same for each request.(even when n=1000). So I assume all the requests are sent one after another ?

Comment: How do you test?

Comment: in the above code snippet , inside publishOn() , I print the Thread name.

Comment: i see, i should be using subscribeOn(). but still even with that it shows the same thread name

Comment: Although you should avoid  calling ‘subscribe‘ explicitly, try to use ‘testRestCall().log()‘  to see thread of the publisher

Comment: actually i found the issue why it runs in the same thread.  Need to create a ParallelFlux , It should be :   parallel().runOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe(...)

Comment: Ref: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux

Comment: You don't really need `parallel` or `runOn`. Please check the updated answer with the test for details. I would suggest you spend time "playing" with Reactive API