# How to parallel two elements processing in Java Reactor Core Flux publisher

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, reactive

I want to complete few tasks parallel using reactive Reactor Core streams. So if there are the long timed task - the next emitted objects must be processed without delay.

So, I have two object, the first took a lot of time to complete. I expect no exact order, but parallel execution. What's wrong?

```java
Flux.just(obj1, obj2)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("parallel", 5))
        .flatMap(Transformator::process)
```

Program is stopped by first element if there are an infinite loop in it's processing.

Comment: It depends on what happens in Transformator.process. Blocking/non-blocking IO or CPU intensive work.

Comment: Of course non-blocking IO operations or something etc.

Comment: If it's non-blocking IO, then you should see concurrency out of the box. By default, it executes 256 items concurrently. If that's not the case for you, then try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring WebFlux | How to wait till a list of Monos finish execution in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74947785/spring-webflux-how-to-wait-till-a-list-of-monos-finish-execution-in-parallel)