How to implement an event based consumer which can process max n messages at any given time?
We have a scenario in the application where user uploads a file from UI.
The file along with some metadata is saved to DB.
Currently, we are running a scheduler which will poll the DB every 15 secs to see if any files needs to be processed.
It can process max upto 10 files at a time.
Currently, the APIs and scheduler are both in the same service deployed on GCP. We are using Spring Webflux. The application runs on 2 pods and we are managing the scheduler to run only on 1 pod at a time by using Shedlock.
We want to move the file processing scheduler part into a separate module/service/component. and change it to an event based mechanism.
We want the producer(on existing service) to send a fileId to kafka or GCP Pub/Sub after saving the file details in DB.
Consumer(on new service) should read the message and process it only if number of files under processing < 10
Once the number of files under processing becomes < 10, a new fileId should be picked(preferably from memory rather than going to DB) and processed.
We can use a scheduler to handle this scenario but just wondering if there is a better way to do it. We would like to avoid using any new component like a cache to avoid additional expenses.
What is the best way to implement it?
Thanks in advance!

Can you elaborate little more ?


The scheduler processes file immediately when it finds it or waits for 10 files to get accumulated ?


What is the bottleneck or problem that you are facing, so that you want to move to a new design ?


number of files under processing < 10 Once the number of files under processing becomes < 10. The number is already < 10 then how can it become < 10 again? Do you mean > 10



Some code snippet should help to understand the problem better but if you just need to limit concurrency ’flatMap’ with additional arguments could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957662/9068895
